# Is it possible to display all validation messages at once?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my cshtml file I have the lines

```
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m, "{{dict.err_comb_cluster}}", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.WarnMailAddress, "{{dict.val_req_err_alarm_email}}", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmailToSendTo, "{{dict.val_req_err_email}}", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

This has the effect that if there is an error concerning the WarnMailAddress or the field EmailToSendTo, the validation message for it will be displayed, but if at the same time there is an error concerning the whole model (that triggers "m => m"), the validation message for this error will not be displayed. It will be only displayed as soon as the other errors have been corrected. In other words, there is a hierarchy of the validation messages.

What we want to achieve is to display all the validation messages at once, ignoring this hierarchy. I've extensively used Google to find possible answers to my question but found none.

Additional information: The validation for the entire model is made using a custom attribute. We defined:

```
    [MetadataType(typeof(CLUSTER_Validation))]
    [CustomValidation(typeof(ClusterUniqueAttribute), "IsValid")]
    public partial class CLUSTER: VMIEntityObject<CLUSTER>
    {
```

and

```
    public class ClusterUniqueAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public static ValidationResult IsValid(CLUSTER cluster)
        {
```

The attributes for the properties are defined inside the class CLUSTER_Validation, and this looks like:

```
    [Display(Description = "Email-Adresse", Name = "Email-Adresse", Order = 15)]
    [RequiredIf("isSendMaiImmidiately", true, ErrorMessage = "If alarm email has been activated, an email address must be provided")]
    public string WarnMailAddress { get; set; }
```